# Flutter in game engine

Tags: flutter

I need help! My question is, Can I use Flutter to create UI for game engine(buttons, color pickers, outliner, inspector like in Unity, Godot or UE ...)? Game Engine is written in C++ and uses OpenGL.
If Flutter can't be used in Game Engine, what is alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

please select one game engine. Godot, Unity, Unreal and co are very different and implementations will probably vary. And chances are it won't work at all.

Use a standard implementation as high-level programming (especially with such advanced engines) often comes at the cost of compatibility with other libraries that are built for vastly different purposes

Comment: UI like Unity is my goal. In short, is Flutter a bad idea for my project?

Comment: it's not just a bad idea it may even be impossible